# Balloon tool tip for a Text Box

Tags: javascript

Im looking for a way to add balloon tip to pop up everytime a text box is clicked and disappear after couple of seconds.  I have searched the web but didn't find anything for a text box.  My text box code is bellow: Help please

```
<td><form:input type='text' id='recipient'
 path="receiverLastName" onkeyup="valid(this)" onblur="valid(this)"/></td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try jQuery UI - tooltip: http://jqueryui.com/tooltip

You would change your html to

```
<td><form:input type='text' id='recipient' title='tool tip to show'
 path="receiverLastName" onkeyup="valid(this)" onblur="valid(this)"/></td>
```

And put this in your javascript (after having included the jquery UI file)

```
$(function() {
    $("#recipient").tooltip();
});
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but your selector should probably be `$("#recipient").tooltip();`, so that it's not for all elements that have a `title` attribute (which is what `$(document)` does...and it's going to take a lot more to do what the OP actually wants. They specifically say "pop up everytime a text box is clicked and disappear after couple of seconds"...while the default behavior is to show when hovered.